# ERROR anaconda_api.is_vscode_available:956

Tags: anaconda

Whenever, I run the command `anaconda-navigator` in my terminal, I am getting the following error: `ERROR anaconda_api.is_vscode_available:956`. I am using deepin os which is based on debian.

Comment: **1.** I have the same problem. For my case I use Linux Mint(based one Debian)      
**2.** During installation the installer did not offer me a prompt to install VS Code as per the installation guide point 8(https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux)

Comment: Using Deepin, same here! ERROR anaconda_api.is_vscode_available:1064